# having problem with converting in bash with Iconv

Tags: bash, shell, type-conversion

`iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0`

If I have a string written in Hebrew language but in English keyboard layout, I want the script to return the same string but in Hebrew keyboard layout.

I'm a new bash user, so it might be a silly problem but I really can't find the answer.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Give me a word: " word

echo "$word" | iconv -t cp1255 | tr $(echo "[/'\קראטוןםפ\]\[שדגכעיחלךף,\זסבהנמצתץ./'\קראטוןםפ}{שדגכעיחלך:\"|זסבהנמצ><?@#$^&~\]" | iconv -t cp1255) "[qwertyuiop\[\]asdfghjkl;'\\zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"|ZXCVBNM<>?@#$^&~\`]"

echo "$word" | tr "[qwertyuiop\[\]asdfghjkl;'\\zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"|ZXCVBNM<>?@#$^&~\`]" $(echo "[/'\קראטוןםפ\]\[שדגכעיחלךף,\זסבהנמצתץ./'\קראטוןםפ}{שדגכעיחלך:\"|זסבהנמצ><?@#$^&~\]"| iconv -t cp1255) | iconv -t cp1255
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] to provide a few examples to test with? The input string and the expected output, ideally enough to cover the full Hebrew alphabet and corner cases where no translation should occur.

Comment: It is also unclear which character encoding your system is set up to use. I get radically different behavior on different systems. I imagine Windows code page 1255 is your system encoding and that that's what the bytes in the `echo` are expressed in?

Comment: The square brackets around the arguments to `tr` are wrong, and you probably want to remove a few of the backslashes.

Comment: Something like this? I had to guess the Hebrew characters from a picture of a Hebrew keyboard so I almost certainly got some of them wrong, and I can't read the script at all. https://ideone.com/jMk5aO

Comment: Hi what you done is working really great...
if you can explain a little bit what is going on there... that would be great

Comment: the out put I got is from the translate were just "??????" got question marks

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to clarify what you have and what you want, I can try to write up an answer. If you can provide a map of the actual characters in the strings and the keyboard layout, that would be super. Perhaps see also [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) which explains some of the concepts.

Comment: If you want to substitute codepoints, not 8-bit ASCII characters, `tr` is definitely not the tool. And I do not understand what `echo ... | iconv` is doing there. Could you please present example input and sample output you want to get? `were just "??????" got question marks` Yes, `tr` replaces _bytes_, not codepoints. You need to use unicode aware tool. Please explain what you code is supposed to do. What is `(echo "[/'\קר...iconv` supposed to achieve? What arguments do you indent to pass to `tr`?

Comment: I try to get a string  from a the user written in english/hebrew and I want it to convert the strings like it was written on the opposite keyboard layout...
for example if I wrote "יקךךם" it will fix my word to the the other language keyboard layout and it will return "hello"(same keystoke as "יקךךם")

Comment: Regardless of the input method (keyboard, file, etc) it seems @avivlevari wants to perform character translation between english and hebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, there is just a simple map of characters, where every character from one set should be replaced by a character from the second set. `tr` (sadly) does not support multi-byte characters nor locale.

GNU sed support Unicode. With `y` command, you can translate between characters:

```
$ echo 'קראטו' | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sed 'y/קראטו/qwert/'
qwert
```

Comment: Hi, as I said Im just starting, can you explain a little bit about locale vars, specifly LC_ALL=C, and sed.
Ty so much for your time

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Locale-Considerations https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)